# How to correctly create Procedures in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm quite new to MySQL and trying to create a simple procedure. The procedure needs to receive an argument which is the column name, and return the table where rows are ordered by the column that was passed as an argument.

Here is what I wrote so far:

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE OrderMyTableBy (ColumnName varchar(45))
    BEGIN 
        SELECT * 
        FROM items
        ORDER BY ColumnName;
    END;//
delimiter ;
```

The procedure is created successfully.

Then I call it as follows:

```
CALL OrderMyTableBy('price')
```

As a result I'm getting the table without ordered rows by price. I got usual table which I would get for this query: `SELECT * FROM items`. So basically it seems that ColumnName is ignored.

Note: if I call the procedure this way: `CALL OrderMyTableBy(helloworld)`. I will get this error:

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'helloworld' in 'field list'

Hope my question was clear. Please comment below if you need more details.
Thanks!

Comment: Mybe that can help http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for some reason the code input didn't work in this answer.

Finally I found out the way to do it:

There are 2 ways in creating procedures:

1. **The correct way is to open Stored Procedures (in the left pane in Schemas) and create it there with the syntax I provided in the question but without "delimiter" rows.**

   `CREATE PROCEDURE OrderByColName (IN col VARCHAR(20))`

   `BEGIN`

   `SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY ', col, ' ASC');`

   `PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;`

   `EXECUTE stmt;`

   `DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;`

   `END`
2. **Another way is to do in Query tab (where i tried previously)**. Here you will need to use this syntax:

`delimiter //`

`CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`PROCEDURE`OrderByColName`(IN col VARCHAR(20))`

`BEGIN`

`SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY ', col, ' ASC');`

`PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;`

`EXECUTE stmt;`

`DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;`

`END`

`// delimiter ;`

Hope it helps. again sorry that code input didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE OrderMyTableBy (ColumnName varchar(45))
 BEGIN 
       SET @t1 = CONCAT("SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY ", ColumnName);
       PREPARE stmt FROM @t1;
       EXECUTE stmt;
       DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt
 END;
```

You will have to make a dynamic query and then call the stored procedure.

Comment: I tested this code and it shows me no rows just like the one from the OP

Comment: @TungFam What's the difference between mine and your answer?